# Inject Dependency into Core Module of a ASP Boilerplate project

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0, hangfire, aspnetboilerplate

I have `NotificationJob` class where I have all the functions related to Notification Feature for my .Net Core application. It has some injected dependencies from Domain services. I am having **a problem trying to inject `INotificationJob` interface of the class into the `CoreModule`** of the project.

I initially tried injecting the interface directly into the `CoreModule` but failed so *I created another module in the same file* called `NotificationModule` where I inject `INotificationJob` interface. Then I try to link it with the `CoreModule` using `[DependsOn(typeof(oasisCoreModule))]` annotation.

**Core Module of the project**

```
[DependsOn(
    typeof(AbpZeroCoreModule),
    typeof(AbpHangfireAspNetCoreModule),
    typeof(AbpWebCommonModule)
    )]
public class oasisCoreModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void PreInitialize()
    {
        Configuration.Modules.AbpWebCommon().SendAllExceptionsToClients = true;

        Configuration.BackgroundJobs.UseHangfire();

        Configuration.Auditing.IsEnabledForAnonymousUsers = true;

        // Declare entity types
        Configuration.Modules.Zero().EntityTypes.Tenant = typeof(Tenant);
        Configuration.Modules.Zero().EntityTypes.Role = typeof(Role);
        Configuration.Modules.Zero().EntityTypes.User = typeof(User);

        oasisLocalizationConfigurer.Configure(Configuration.Localization);

        // Enable this line to create a multi-tenant application.
        Configuration.MultiTenancy.IsEnabled = oasisConsts.MultiTenancyEnabled;

        // Configure roles
        AppRoleConfig.Configure(Configuration.Modules.Zero().RoleManagement);

        Configuration.Settings.Providers.Add<AppSettingProvider>();
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(oasisCoreModule).GetAssembly());
    }

    public override void PostInitialize()
    {
        IocManager.Resolve<AppTimes>().StartupTime = Clock.Now;

    }
}

// This is the custom module that I created in the same file as the core module.
[DependsOn(typeof(oasisCoreModule))]
public class NotificationModule : AbpModule
{
    INotificationJob _job;

    public NotificationModule(INotificationJob job)
    {
        _job = job;
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }

    public override void PostInitialize()
    {
        _job.Loop();
    }
}
```

**`INotificationJob` Interface I am *Injecting* into the `NotificationModule`**

```
public interface INotificationJob: IDomainService
{
    void Loop();
    void CheckTickets();
    void CheckReminders(string email, string ticket);
}
```

**Class Implementation of `INotificationJob` Interface**

```
public class NotificationJob: DomainService, INotificationJob
{

    private readonly ITicketRefManager _ticketRefManager;
    private readonly IClientManager _clientManager;
    private readonly IEmailManager _emailManager;

    public NotificationJob(
        ITicketRefManager ticketRefManager, 
        IClientManager clientManager, 
        IEmailManager emailManager,
        )
    {
        _ticketRefManager = ticketRefManager;
        _clientManager = clientManager;
        _emailManager = emailManager;
    }

    public void Loop()
    {
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => CheckTickets(), Cron.Minutely);
    }
}
```

When I run the solution, I am presented with an error saying as shown:
[image]

Are there any other steps that I need to take to complete the Dependency Injection process? Or are the steps that I described flawed?

Comment: I think you must update project from source "BoilerPlate"..

Comment: do you try to inject INotificationJob service in application layer? I see you have NotificationModule  depends on oasisCoreModule. To jnject the service, may be you should declare oasisCoreModule depend on NotificationModule

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with you "interface injecting", but you can try this if I understand correctly what you're trying to do :

**Core Module**

```
[...]
public override void PostInitialize()
{
    var recurrentJobs = IocManager.Resolve<NotificationJob>();
    RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists("JobName");
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("JobName", () => recurrentJobs.CheckTickets(), Cron.Minutely);
}
```

**Your class**

```
public class NotificationJob : ISingletonDependency
{

    private readonly ITicketRefManager _ticketRefManager;
    private readonly IClientManager _clientManager;
    private readonly IEmailManager _emailManager;

    public NotificationJob(
        ITicketRefManager ticketRefManager, 
        IClientManager clientManager, 
        IEmailManager emailManager,
        )
    {
        _ticketRefManager = ticketRefManager;
        _clientManager = clientManager;
        _emailManager = emailManager;
    }

    public void CheckTickets()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Does it helps ?

Comment: Appreciate your suggestions! It got me through the stage and now I'm seeing a different error message:

`Could not load file or assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`